# Problems with own filters or why list doesn't have method "apend" (Python)

Tags: python, django

I try to write my own filter. But it doesn't work and I don't understand why. Table regimeCalendar contains rows with same columns value "dates" and I want that my filter return only distinct values, maybe I go in wrong way? It is an error that points in the template in the string which uses my filter:

```
'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'append'
```

My filter file:

```
...
    @register.filter(is_safe=False)
    def get_distinct_dates(value):
        """Adds the arg to the value."""
        try:
            results = []
            for item in value:
                add = True
                for result in results:
                    if result == item.regimeCalendar.date:
                        add = False
                        break
                if add:
                    results.append(item.regimeCalendar.date)
            while len(results) < 21:
                result.append("")
            return results
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            return ''
```

models.py file:

```
class RegimeCalendar(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date']
        unique_together = ('patient', 'date')


class AppointmentCalendar(models.Model):
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    appointment = models.ForeignKey(Appointments)
    regimeCalendar = models.ForeignKey(RegimeCalendar)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    doctor_mark = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    nurse_mark = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py file:

```
...
context['AppointmentCalendar'] = AppointmentCalendar.objects.filter(patient=patient)
...
```

my template html file:

```
{% for item in AppointmentCalendar|get_distinct_dates %}
                ...
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You just need to add an "s". `results.append("")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
result.append("")  # result is a date object
```

to

```
results.append("")  # results is a list
```